# Remove beginning and trailing new line characters from NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

How can one remove **only** the beginning and trailing new line **\n** from a NSString.

For e.g.

```
@"\n\n\n\Hi\nHow are you\nToday.\n\n\n\n"
```

output:

```
@"Hi\nHow are you\nToday."
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use **stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet** method of nsstring which Returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the receiver characters contained in a given character set.

### Swift

```
yourString = yourString.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

### Objective-C

```
  yourString = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]
```

Answer (score 14):

```
NSString *string = @"\n \n  new lines or white spaces in front and at the end \n \n ";
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

```
var yourString = "\n your string \n"
yourString = yourString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

**Output** `"your string"`

Answer (score 1):

Try This it work for me ,

```
  NSString *trimmedValue = [value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Hope this will help some one .